# Mux handler not receiving all the query parameters passed from curl post

Tags: go, mux

I am not able to receive all the query parameters using Mux. Only the first part is received

```
func main() {
    router := mux.NewRouter()
    router.HandleFunc("/resize", resizeImageFromPayload).Methods("POST")
    log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":8080", router))
}

func resizeImageFromPayload(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    widthParameter := r.URL.Query().Get("width")
    heightParameter := r.URL.Query().Get("height")
    fmt.Println(r.URL.String())
    fmt.Println(widthParameter)
    fmt.Println(heightParameter)
   //More code..
}
```

When I call the api using curl `curl -XPOST http://localhost:8080/resize?width=100&height=100 -o img_resize.png -F "file=@snap1.png"` This is what it prints:

```
/resize?width=100
100
```

it seems like it omitted the &height=100 part. Any idea ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your shell is interpreting the `&` as your intention to fork the curl command to the background.  Wrap your URL in quotes to see the desired output.

Comment: Try wrapping your URL in single quotes when you run it in shell.

Comment: thanks it works :) not go related after all

Comment: this is realed to  GET http method, not POST

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The URL `http://localhost:8080/resize?width=100&height=100` contains a special character `&` that has [another meaning](http://bashitout.com/2013/05/18/Ampersands-on-the-command-line.html) to shell.

In order to use ampersand (`&`) as an actual character inside the URL, you need to put the URL in quotes: **"**`http://localhost:8080/resize?width=100&height=100`**"**

Comment: Thanks. This was exactly what the guys in the comments said. Marking as accepted answer.